# Join MS Word documents

Tags: .net, ms-word, document, splice

What is the recommended strategy for in code to splice a set of MS Word documents together into one?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AppendWordDocuments.aspx

Or any of these:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=append+microsoft+word+documents

Comment: Thanks, the codeproject.com project solved the problem, I'll use that as my template. :-) Great find. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go look at the various SDKs available.  This is much easier to do if you are using Word 2007, as the file is actually a zip file containing various XML documents.  MS even has an SDK called "[Open XML Format SDK 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AD0B72FB-4A1D-4C52-BDB5-7DD7E816D046&displaylang=en)" which provides strongly typed classes for working with the new office format.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot assume that only the current version of Word is being used, I need to support older versions as well, so I cannot go the DocX route.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Open XML (ie docx), there are 2 basic
approaches to solving this problem:

The first is to do what is necessary so ids point to the correct
relationship (eg for images, hyperlinks), and styles are defined etc.  A
good explanation of what you need to do can be found  at
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx

[PowerTools](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2009/03/19/announcing-the-release-of-powertools-for-open-xml-v1-1.aspx) implements that.

The second is to use altChunk:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx