# Running Word from a SharePoint Workflow

Tags: .net, sharepoint, interop, workflow, ms-word

based on [Join MS Word documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630449/join-ms-word-documents) I have made a console application that splices multiple word files into one. Now I want to do the same from a Workflow in SharePoint. In short, my code before it fails looks like this:

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc = null;
oWord.Visible = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents oDocs = oWord.Documents;
object oFile = tmpFileName;
oDoc = oDocs.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
oDoc.Activate();
```

When I reach oDoc.Activate(), I'm thrown the following exception, even though I only have one instance of the workflow running and no other instances of Word is running on the server:

The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

Why do I get this error?? What would make the application busy?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are Word 2007 Documents, I think that you should look into the Word File Formats and see if the Article from Microsoft helps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295.aspx

Office Interop is always a bit unstable, and running it on a server is the last thing I would recommend unless there is really no other way to do it.

In a Sharepoint Environment, maybe the [Document Converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms518493.aspx) can somehow help, although I have no experience with them - just as a hint at something to look at.

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't all Office 2007 documents, most of them are 2003. Thanks for the Document Converter link, I'll be sure to read it through.

Comment: Would Migration Planning Manager (http://tinyurl.com/tdt6r) be a good way to convert the documents to Word 2007 and then go the Office Open XML SDK route?

Comment: I have no experience with Migration of existing documents to 2007 since I always only needed to open and re-save them in Office 2007, but if your users are not Office 2007 yet that that would not be an option anyway. I don't know if you can batch-convert documents to 2007 with any tool :/

Answer (score 0):

The Office applications are not built to run in a server environment - they are purely desktop applications. Don't call them from a server.